# Is upload count as PHP execution time?

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, upload

Should I increase runtime / execution time of PHP for uploads? Normally it is set to 30 seconds. And, if I should increase this execution time, can I make it work with `set_time_limit()` on Windows?

Comment: Nope, request parsing is not included into execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading is controller by separate limit, the [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)
There are other variables at play, as the memory_limit, post_max_size, upload_max_size, max_file_uploads. See [the File Uploads section](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in the php.ini documentation